# How to count and limit the text from 2 text fields in a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i tried to count and limit the user inputs from two text fields. that means max char is 20, then user can enter only 20 char in both text fields.I tried like this

```
$(document).ready( function() {

jQuery.fn.getLength = function(){
var count = 0;
var max=$("#max").val();
this.each(function(){
   count += jQuery(this).val().length;
     });   
 var rem=max-count;
return rem;
};

var $inputs= jQuery('#left,#right');
$inputs.bind('keyup',function(){
    var remain=$inputs.getLength();
 jQuery('#count').html($inputs.getLength());
    $("#left").keyup(function(){
        if($("#left").val().length > remain){
        $("#left").val($("#left").val().substr(0, remain));
        }
    });

    $("#right").keyup(function(){
        if($("#right").val().length > remain){
        $("#right").val($("#right").val().substr(0, remain));
        }
    });

});

});
```

but it only works for single text box, doesn't take values from 2 fields. any help please..

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo pls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is this code, it detects the keypress in either #left or #right, if the count of the two is more than 20, it removes the last character typed

```
$("#left,#right").keyup(function () {
    var charCount = $('#left').val().length + $('#right').val().length;
    if (charCount > 20) {
        difference = -Math.abs(charCount - 20);
        $(this).val($(this).val().slice(0, difference));
    }
});
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/k8nMY/

My first solution worked on keydown and used return false to stop further entry, however this had the effect of disabling backspace and other keys.

This solution, which executes on keyup waits until after the key is pressed then counts characters. If the number is over 20 it will remove the last character typed. This way, the user can still press backspace and make changes as they wish, but not go over 20 chars.

I have also modified the script further, what it does is detect ANY change, e.g. a paste of a long string. It removes the 'difference' above 20 characters.

This should be a complete solution to the problem.

Comment: you are correct, updated to work on keyup, explanation also updated

Comment: What if I paste a string in? You're only trimming off the last character!

Comment: once the count reaches 20, it disabled the fields, but i need to edit those fields again.. its returning false..

Answer (score 2):

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/EEbuJ/2/

### JQuery

```
$('#left, #right').keyup(function(e) {
    if (maxLen() <= 20)
    {
        // Save the value in a custom data attribute
        $(this).data('val', $(this).val());
    } else {
        // over-ride value with saved data
        $(this).val($(this).data('val'));
    }
});

function maxLen() {
    var x = 0;

    $('#left, #right').each(function() {
        x += $(this).val().length;
    });

    return x;
};
```

This will save the typed in value for your inputs to a custom data attribute, if the total number of characters in the specified inputs is no more than 20.

When the maximum number of characters is reached then we stop saving the typed in value and revert the value back to our previous save (i.e. less than the maxiumum) effectively undo-ing the value.

Comment: well that is all text inputs... nice function, but no explanation and not what op asked for... most probably this will count too many inputs

Comment: @Vogel612 updated and added some explanation. Thought the code (and its comments) was prety self-explanatory, but I take your point :)

Comment: nice solution, however when pasting over-length text it ignores your paste and reverts to previous value.

Comment: @StevePapa That was my intention, but if the user wants that, then I will make it so :-P How's this: http://jsfiddle.net/EEbuJ/3/ ??

Answer (score 0):

Well it should be easy one: http://jsfiddle.net/4DETE/1/

```
var textLength =$inputs.eq(0).val().length+$inputs.eq(1).val().length;
if(textLength>=20)
    return false
```

just count length of values, if you'll have more elements to limit, use jquery.each to iterate inputs

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can do `$inputs.getLength()` as $inputs is an array and thus will return the arraylength: 2
You will have to add up the overall sign length in both inputs:

```
$('#left,#right').keydown(function(){
    var leftlength = $('#left').val().length;
    var rightlength = $('#right').val().length;
   if(leftlength + rightlength > 20)
   {
    return false;
   }
});
```

or to make it shorter

```
if($('#left').val().length+$('#right').val().length >20){return false;}
```